# Patching an app that updates frequently

Tags: patching, patch-reversing, c#

Hello i am working with an app coded in c# which updates very often usually within 2-3 days or sometimes every 12 hours
The updates are really needed for the app to work
So i was wondering what can i use to patch the functions i want automatically
Been using dnspy for now but it is a big hassle doing the same thing every day
I am looking for suggestions, probabily dll injection or else
Thanks

Also the app uses an encrypted connection to comunicate with server, is it possible to create an app to hook/sniff the data in real time as i have the decryption key?

Comment: bump.. anybody?

Comment: i have decompiled it, every decompiler i have used is unable to give full correct code however i am able to edit the strings i want, i was wondering if there was a way like monitoring the process/exe and once the md5 changes automatically patch the code(functions i want changed/added). Also what about using another exe file to inject another dll into the process and the dll handles the override functions. Im just speaking out in the dust and looking for ideas or examples. About traffic the exe file listenes to a specific ip:port, probabily using httplistener class will catch the data received?

Comment: How does the app update? Can you modify the launcher so it runs your patch utility after updating? Changing strings in the final jar should be as easy as find & replace on the executable